# how to format time with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON feed that drupal spits out time in this format:   **2010-12-16T04:41:35Z**

How do I go about formating it to X minutes/hours ago?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [timeago jQuery plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) which can be used programtically like

```
var t = jQuery.timeago("2010-12-16T04:41:35Z");
```

or on HTML elements like

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</time>
<script type="javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("time.timeago").timeago();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I've used this plugin, it works perfectly and it is very easy to use. You can change the wording used just by doing $.timeago.settings.minute = "a minute"; for example.

Answer (score 2):

I think [something on this page will help you](http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/8-Widely-Used-Calendar-Date-Picker-and-Time-Formatting-jQuery-Plugins-that-Web-Developers-Should-Know.aspx). There's a couple formatting jQuery plugins toward the bottom. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a highly relevant Stack Overflow post:  [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regexp object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) in JS to build your own regular expression, separate hours-minutes-secs from the original string and then do whatever you want.

Tip: actual_date - your original string time

Answer (score 0):

does the 04:41:35 part is correct? or do you need like to take into consideration time zones and stuff?

because basically this can work:

```
var str = "2010-12-16T04:41:35Z"
var arr = str.split("T")
arr[0] = arr[0].split("-")
arr[1] = (arr[1].replace(/Z/ig,"")).split(":")
var year = arr[0][0]
var month = parseInt(arr[0][1],10)-1
var day = arr[0][2]
var hours = arr[1][0]
var minutes = arr[1][1]
var seconds = arr[1][2]
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, 0);
var now = (new Date())
var diffMS = now.getTime() - d.getTime()
//alert ("difference in milliseconds: " + diffMS)

var hoursago = diffMS/1000/60
var ANDminutes = (diffMS - Math.floor(hoursago) * 1000*60)/1000

alert (Math.floor(hoursago) + " hours and " + ANDminutes + " minutes ago")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<shameless_plug>
```

Here's a library which give you a humanized time difference.

https://github.com/layam/js_humanized_time_span

The output is completely customizable, allowing you to set different output formats for various time bands; So you could have:

```
'10 seconds ago'
```

or

```
'3 days and 2 hours ago'
```

you can even set custom time units.

Additionally it's native JS and so doesn't rely on any framework.

```
</shameless_plug>
```