# Converting a date string into UTC+0530 format using javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, string-formatting

I have a date in the format `14-Feb-2011`, but I want to convert it into the format `Mon Feb 14 10:13:50 UTC+0530 2011`. How Can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you utilizing a javascript library or is this vanilla javascript?

Comment: I think this will be helpful [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Using `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))` you can create a Date-object from a specific UTC time.

I tried this code and it returned proper date (In Indian Locale)

```
var d=Date.parse("14,Feb,2011");
document.write(new Date(d));
```

Output:

```
Mon Feb 14 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) .
```

---

Here's an example of converting between different time zones.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

//Set you offset here like +5.5 for IST
var offsetIST = 5.5;


//Set you offset here like -8 for PST
var offsetPST = -8;

//Create a new date from the Given string
var d=new Date(Date.parse("14,Feb,2011"));

//To convert to UTC datetime by subtracting the current Timezone offset
var utcdate =  new Date(d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset()*60000));

//Then cinver the UTS date to the required time zone offset like back to 5.5 for IST
var istdate =  new Date(utcdate.getTime() - ((-offsetIST*60)*60000));

//Then cinver the UTS date to the required time zone offset like back to -8 for PST (Canada US)
var pstdate=  new Date(utcdate.getTime() - ((-offsetPST*60)*60000));

document.write(d);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(utcdate);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(istdate);
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(pstdate);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
Mon Feb 14 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Sun Feb 13 2011 18:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Mon Feb 14 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Sun Feb 13 2011 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Its writing IST every where because new Date() always show date as local timezone (which is IST for me) but above datetime are actually **Original**, **UTC**, **IST**, **PST** respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date("14-Feb-2011");
```

this will give an output of 
Mon Feb 14 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)