# how convert date string format into UTC+0530 format using javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a date string into UTC+0530 format using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990367/converting-a-date-string-into-utc0530-format-using-javascript)

I have date is "`14-Feb-2011`" in this form and

i wants convert into `Mon Feb 14 10:13:50 UTC+0530 2011` format

using **javascript**

Comment: **Please don't double-post**, this is an exact duplicate of your earlier question: [how convert date string into UTC+0530 format using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990367/how-convert-date-string-into-utc0530-format-using-javascript)

Comment: If you see a dupe like this, flag it as low quality and the moderators will delete it.