# Convert datetime string to UTC in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

How can we convert datetime string to UTC in javascript. We are getting following JSON from REST service

```
[  
   {  
      "CreationTime":"June 2, 2015 8:04:53 PM IST",
      "category":"UI",
      "severity":"MAJOR",
      "source":"BILLING",
      "status":"ASSIGNED"
   }
]
```

we are able to get `CreationTime` into a String variable but unable to convert to UTC.  Any idea to convert this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [toUTCString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString):

```
var toUTC = new Date("June 2, 2015 8:04:53").toUTCString()
```

In Javascript you can use this method to convert a date from a `Date() object`, but not from a `IST string`. So you need format this string to a `Date() object` , then you can convert it to UTC. In **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4990486/1074519)** topic says what I mean.

<kbd>Note</kbd> If you try `June 2, 2015 8:04:53 PM IST` JavasScript take it as invalid date, for that you have to use `.replace()` function to remove the `IST` part of the string.

Comment: var dateString ="June 2, 2015 8:04:53 PM IST";
var toUTC = new Date(dateString).toUTCString()
document.write(toUTC); 

i am getting output as Invalid Date. Any idea to solve this

Comment: you can use this method to convert a date from a `Date() object`, but not from a `IST string`, see my answer edit.