# How to change format from string date to utc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

With Typescript, I want to change date/time format from string to UTC. 
Currently, that occurs invalid.

like this:
2018/10/27+16:00 => 20181027T01000Z

```
import * as moment from 'moment'

dates=${moment(`${String(date)}`).format('YYYYMMDD')}T${moment(`${String(time)}`)
     .utc()
     .format('HHmm')}Z/${moment(`${String(date)}`).format('YYYYMMDD')}T${moment(
     `${String(time)}`,
)
     .utc()
     .format('HHmm')}
```

Adding to this, I want to add 30min to second time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert datetime string to UTC in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163409/convert-datetime-string-to-utc-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

In moment, you can use add like this to add 30mins

```
moment().add(30, 'minutes');
```

And set it to UTC,just use this:

```
moment.utc().valueOf()
```