# Javascript, typecasting needed (I think)

Tags: javascript, date, casting, compare, typecast-operator

I am reading a date from local storage and then need to compare it to another date but it does not work. I think I need to typecast it but am very rusty with Javascript, please have a look, my code is not much:

```
// ****** ### IMPORTANT: The below line returns "2011,3,20" ### *******
var da_expiry_date = localStorage['list_expiry_date']; 

var today_date = new Date();
var future_date = new Date();

future_date.setFullYear(da_expiry_date+2);
alert (future_date+"\n"+today_date);

    if (future_date>today_date) {
        alert("1");
    }
    else {
        alert("2");
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're comment at the top is correct and `da_expiry_date` is returning a string, then you will need to typecast it to date before you can do anything meaningful. [The easiest way to do this is with oneof the methods listed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript) The problem with converting a string to a date is knowing the format; if you have all the pieces separated you can just use one of the other [date constructors.](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/date.html) :D

As it is, you code is trying to take the string `"2011,3,20"`, add the number `2` to it, and set it as the full year of `future_date`. The browser ends up converting 2 to a string and concatenating that to the end, giving you `"2011,3,202"`. `setFullYear` expects an int instead of a string, so it can't do its job.

You probably want that line switched to this after you've got your date properly converted:

```
future_date.setFullYear(da_expiry_date.getFullYear()+2);
```

Comment: Thanks! Selected your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're attempting with this line:

```
da_expiry_date+2;
```

The result of that is:

```
2011,3,202
```

...which is not a valid value to pass to `setFullYear`. So, let's parse the date:

```
var da_expiry_date = localStorage['list_expiry_date']; 

function pad(num, n) {
    return ("0" + num).slice(-n);
}

function formatDate(date) {
    var p = date.split(",");
    return [pad(p[0], 4), pad(p[1], 2), pad(p[2], 2)].join("-");
}

var today_date = new Date();
var future_date = new Date(formatDate(da_expiry_date));

alert (future_date+"\n"+today_date);

if (future_date>today_date) {
    alert("1");
} else {
    alert("2");
}
```

If you're attempting to add `2` to the year, then do it after you've split the date into its components:

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var p = date.split(",");
    p[0] = p[0] * 1 + 2; // add 2 to the year
    return [pad(p[0], 4), pad(p[1], 2), pad(p[2], 2)].join("-");
}
```

Or, even better, parameterize it:

```
function formatDate(date, n) {
    var p = date.split(",");
    p[0] = p[0] * 1 + n; // add n to the year
    return [pad(p[0], 4), pad(p[1], 2), pad(p[2], 2)].join("-");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse it as a date first, try this:

```
var dateFromLocalStorage = function(s) {
  var m = (""+s).match(/^(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)$/);
  return (m) ? new Date(m[1], m[2], m[3]) : null;
};
dateFromLocalStorage("2011,3,20"); // => Wed Apr 20, 2011 ...
```

Note that the date constructor takes the month as a zero based integer, so Jan=0, Feb=1, Mar=2, etc.