# How to convert dateTime format in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How i could convert datetime `5/8/2011 12:00:00 AM` (m/d/yyyy) to dd-MMM-yyyy like `08-May-2011` in javascript.

Comment: I don't think you'd ever want `5/8/2011` to be `08-Jun-2011`. I guess you meant `08-May-2011`? (although if I saw `5/8/2011` I'd read it as 5th of August. ambiguous date formats are a *really* bad idea)

Comment: yeah it's right, but you know the format whatever you get so just extract with javascript function and create new formatted date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link is a good resource you can use for.

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Alternatively, you need to get the individual part and concatenate them as needed like below.

```
var now = new Date();
var hour        = now.getHours();
var minute      = now.getMinutes();
var second      = now.getSeconds();
var monthnumber = now.getMonth();
var monthday    = now.getDate();
var year        = now.getYear();

String myOutput = monthday + "-" + monthnumer + "-" + year;
```

To get the month name instead of month number, you need to define an array like below

```
var arrMonths = new Array ("Jan","Feb"....};

   String myOutput = monthday + "-" + arrMonths[monthnumer-1] + "-" + year;
```

Comment: I have dateTime in var using getElementById,how i convert it to datetime

Comment: you should write like this, var now =new Date(document.getElementById ("yourid").value);

Answer (score 0):

check below link hope you got some idea

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/519332-how-convert-datetime-format-using-javascript

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

[similar question solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)