# Jquery - How can i create a datetime in microformat

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timestamp, microtime

what ist the fastest way to create this date format with javascript/jquery?

```
Wed, 03 Aug 2011 15:49:22 -0700
```

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a date in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked before
For example [How to convert dateTime format in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438433/how-to-convert-datetime-format-in-javascript) which links to the useful http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

To answer this in plain JS, here is something that will give you the date in local time, i.e. your -0700 becomes +0200 on my computer

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/HMkLd/

```
function getMicroformat(date) {
  var d = date.toString();    
  var parts = d.split(" ");
  return parts[0]+", "+
         parts[2]+" "+
         parts[1]+" "+
         parts[3]+" "+
         parts[4]+" "+
         parts[5].replace(/[A-Z]/g,"");
}

// OR

function getMFReg(d) {
  var reg = /(\D{3}) (\D{3}) (\d{2}) (\d{4}) ([:|\d]{8}) \D{3}([+|-|\d]{3})/
  return d.toString().replace(reg,"$1, $3 $2 $4 $5 $6")
}

var str = "Wed, 03 Aug 2011 15:49:22 -0700";
var d = new Date(str);
document.write(str +"<br>=><br>"+getMicroformat(d));
document.write("<br>=><br>"+getMFReg(d));
```

Comment: It is INCREDIBLY annoying to be downvoted without a comment. Very unprofessional.

Comment: So was it useful to you @Peter?

Answer (score -4):

use this,

```
var d1=new Date();
d1.toString('yyyy-MM-dd');       //returns "2009-06-29"
d1.toString('dddd, MMMM ,yyyy')  //returns "Monday, June 29,2009"
```

you can set your format which you want

Comment: In what browser does date.toString() take parameters??? And the asker wants  DDD, dd MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss TZ

Comment: you send that link http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format, and you vote down, i think you have disease of sort team memory loss

Comment: How so? the link I provide use a library and the code would be d.format(....) and not d.toString(....) so what are you talking about? (and I formatted your code for you - use the {} button )