# How can I format a datetime into a string in javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a c# DateTime that shows up as Date(1309513219184) when I try to include it in my web page with javascript. I would like it to show as something like 07/01/2011 09:30.

Is there a way that I can format this in javascript or should I first do some kind of c# format and then print as a javascript string?

How can I format it?

Comment: How are you assigning this and to what control ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
// var d = new Date(dateString);
// var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
d.toString();    // or d.toLocaleString()
```

Or you can use a library like [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

Comment: datejs is really for parsing dates and manipulating them with some logic, not really display/format.

Comment: You can pass a variety of format strings to it's `toString` method to get the desired formatted output: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString

Comment: good to know! I was not aware datejs supported this functionality

Answer (score 1):

You can format in javascript. There already same questions posted earlier in StackOverflow.

[How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/476105/684934)

Answer (score 0):

From [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date/2316066#2316066) we can see that you can parse the date out using:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

Substring without the 2nd argument will take the substring from the starting index to the end, giving you:

```
1309513219184)
```

Which JavaScript can successfully parse into an int of value 1309513219184.  This value represents the number of millseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

As for formatting, my personal preference is the [date.format.js](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format).  For example:

```
dateFormat(date, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:MM:ss")
```

Comment: I wish I didn't have to load another js :-(

Comment: You can certainly accomplish string output with on your own using the getMonth, getMinutes, etc that are built-in (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

I would change the DateTime variable into a string with the desired format in your C# code before sending the value to the client. You could use the String.Format method for this:

`var newDateTime = Format.String("{MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm}", oldDateTime);`

Comment: This isn't practical if you are serializing your data in JSON format.  The given form in the question is in fact what you get when serializing a Date object into JSON from C#.  Plus, if you actually want to operate on the resulting Date, you'd still have to parse it anyway.