# How to change date format from dd/mm/yyyy to default format through Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, format

In my Database i am having date in "dd/mm/yyyy" format. In the sucess function I am getting like '29/06/2006". I want to convert this form "dd/mm/yyyy" format to default format (default format means "Thu Jun 29 2006 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)")

I tried the following ways

1) way

```
xx = 29/06/2006 
new Date(xx)
```

2)way

```
dateFormat(xx, "ddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT")
```

Both giving wrong date,month,year. Result as (Tue, May 6th, 2008, 12:00:00 AM)

I am giving input as Jun 29 2006 but after conversion it'a showing May 6th, 2008.

Comment: There is a similar question about this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [javascript dateFormat](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var mydate = new Date(getDateFromFormat(/*Date value in string*/, /*Format of date sting*/));
```

http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/

Answer (score 0):

this could do it:

```
var dt  = '01/05/2011'.split(/\-|\s/)  // allows for 01-05-2011 also
    dat = new Date(dt.reverse().join('/'));
```