# Get month name instead of number

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jQuery datepicker plugin. I can get the month number by

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth()+1
```

How can I get the month name directly (i.e. without using a `switch case`)?

Comment: See this SO question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript

Comment: hey @dacwe, I went through the question, I was looking for something more direct (If it exists), but it should work thou.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want a simple solution this is it:

```
var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
               "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

var selectedMonthName = months[$("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth()];
```

---

A more complicated but more customizable way would be to use a formatter (my comment). Then see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript).

Comment: You're duplicating a lot of functionality here though, datepicker already has all this sort of functionality built in.

Answer (score 7):

Edit: I guess getMonthName doesn't work?

Well really the 'right' way to do this is to use formatDate: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

```
var monthName = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM', $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate'));
```

Comment: err. I hit it on Firebug's console and it says ".getMonthName is not a function". Could you please be little more specific.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old thread but hey, improvements are always welcome (I hope!)

This works well if you have optional languages set.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "monthNames")[$("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth()]
```