# Javascript - convert number to month name

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, numbers

I have a very simple problem but for some reason I can't find the answer for it.

```
label.forEach(function(value){
    months.push(value['month']);
    revenue.push(value['revenue']);
});
```

The `label` is an array of numbers and revenue, in my case this is

```
[
{month: 9, revenue: 400}, 
{month: 11, revenue: 500},
{month: 12, revenue: 600}
]
```

This is a forEach loop in javascript, it pushes revenue and a month number into two seperate arrays, the problem is that the month is a number (e.g. 12) but I want the .push() to push a month name instead (December), I can't seem to find anything so I was hoping anyone here could help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get month name from Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date)

Comment: So this month starts from 0 or 1?

Comment: @brk It starts from 1

Comment: @hsz Already tried that one but the array in the answer already has month names not the numbers

Comment: post your `label` array...

Comment: @Mamun I updated my answer

Comment: There is no key named `month` and `revenue` in the array. Then how you access those in the loop?

Comment: @Mamun sorry, I updated my answer again

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
           "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

var selectedMonthName = months[value['month']];
```

look at the links

[stack 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7499504/1892085)

Comment: Totally looked over this anwer but it worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: If the months start from 1 (January is 1) you would have to access the month like this `var selectedMonthName = months[value['month'] - 1];` because January is at index 0

Comment: I am using this with a blank string at index zero. Defensive coding would make me test for a  month with value 0

Answer (score 14):

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'long' }).format(new Date('1')); // January
```

Can be achieved using [Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)

Comment: This is the best solution and utilising the newest features of Javascript. There is less need for third party libraries and making your own functions with `Intl.DateTimeFormat`

Answer (score 7):

This can be easily done using moment.js.

```js
var months = [];
months.push(moment().month(0).format("MMMM"));
console.log(months);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just call moment.months();

Comment: If you only need "Jan" not the full name of the month, format("MMM") like this. Only 3 M instead of 4 M.

Answer (score 1):

another simple way of doing it is with a map, create one like this

```
const monthNumberToLabelMap = {
  [1]: 'January',
  [2]: 'February',
  [3]: 'March',
  [4]: 'April',
  [5]: 'May',
  [6]: 'June',
  [7]: 'July',
  [8]: 'August',
  [9]: 'September',
  [10]: 'October',
  [11]: 'November',
  [12]: 'December',
}
```

then use the map in your code like this

```
label.forEach(function(value){
    months.push(monthNumberToLabelMap[value['month']]);
    revenue.push(value['revenue']);
});
```

note:

it wasn't clear from your question what the format of your month data is, default javascript months are 0-11 in which case you would have change my map

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>

    var monthNumber='03';
    var month = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
    var monthIndex = moment().month(monthNumber[1]-1).format("M");
    var selectedMonthName = month[monthIndex-1];
    alert(selectedMonthName);
```