# How to convert a string date "2019-04-21T12:08:35" to SimpleDateFormat, there by convert to Date?

Tags: java, datetime

For normal date Strings like `"2019-04-08 08:35"`

```
   SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm");
```

but What shall be the shortest conversion for dates like

```
   "2019-04-21T12:08:35"
```

Comment: Advice - Don't do it. `SimpleDateFormat` is long outdated, use java-8's new java.time features. Even IF you do want to do it, where is your attempt?

Comment: Side note, `yyyy-dd-yy hh:mm` is not correct for your example.

Comment: Use this if you are still using SimpleDateFormat `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` -- thanks updated

Comment: LocalDateTime.parse("2019-04-21T12:08:35")

Comment: /!\ Alternative answer is javascript, not java /!\

Comment: FWIW it has been mentioned that this question is a possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion) and [How to convert string to Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785014/how-to-convert-string-to-date-object), but it was reopened. I wanted to let the links stand here as reference.

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDateFormat` is not a `Date`, it's used to

1. Convert String to Date
2. Format Date to String

You can parse String to `java.time.LocalDateTime`  directly since java8:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-04-21T12:08:35");
System.out.println(localDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before Java8 :

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-yy'T'hh:mm:ss");
```