# Unparseable Date in android, pattern character 'T'

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, date-parsing, datetime-parsing

Is there any way I can remove characters from an EditText brought from a JSONObject response? Example: 2019-03-06T00:00:00 and only present the chain in this way: 2019-02-10, when making the conversion I throw an exception which is:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'
```

Code:

```
 String yourJsonDateString =  jsonResponse.getString(DataManager.Birthdate);
                    try {
                        Date yourJsonDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS").parse(yourJsonDateString);
                        String newDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(yourJsonDate);
                        System.out.println(newDateString);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: What are you using to parse the Json string? What you are receiving is a Date from the Json perspective not a String.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2597111/6383857) out

Comment: From the json get this string.  `"2019-03-06T00:00:00"`

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Your code runs nicely on my JDK 11.

Comment: Nice link, @StaticBeagle, thanks. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023929/5772882) may match even a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

To simply `2019-03-06T00:00:00` into `2019-03-06` you can try this.

```
String dt = dateString.substring(0, 10)
```

if you use <1000 year dates, or even BCE format. you can use this

```
String dt = dateString.substring(0, dateString.indexOf("T"))
```

Comment: Careful, this will fail for <1000 year dates. Should do something like `dateString.substring(0, dateString.indexOf("T"))`