# Create a appended string with separating date time with date in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, datetime

I am doing something to prepare a string to display in a format in server side but now I have to replace it in javascript so my server side code is:

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string date = now.GetDateTimeFormats('d')[0];
            string time = now.GetDateTimeFormats('t')[0];

                txtFileName.Value = someString.Length > 10 ? someString.Substring(0, 10).TrimEnd() + "_" + date + "_" + time : someString.TrimEnd() + "_" + date + "_" + time;
            txtFileName.Value = txtFileName.Value.Replace(' ', '_');
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although JavaScript provides a bunch of methods for getting and setting parts of a date object, it lacks a simple way to format dates and times according to a user-specified mask.

Check these [date function](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/)  and follow following links:
[Formatting a date in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)
[How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

```
var d = new Date();
var datepart = d.getDate() + "  " + d.getMonth() + " " + d.getFullYear();
```

using [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) object same you can create time format also.

To create filename format use javascript replace[enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method

```
var myNewString = myOldString.replace("username", visitorName);
```

Check this to create trim method or [extend javascript String Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-to-trim-a-string-in-javascript)

Hope this is enough to convert your server side code in java script...

Answer (score 0):

check out [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/), it has very powerfull date manipulation functions

Comment: i can't use any other library due to some constraints.