# Different line of text each hour

Tags: javascript, time

I'm trying to make a site that displays a different line of text depending on the hour (GMT). I have tried using javascript, but I'm very much a beginner! I've managed to piece the following bit of code together but can't seem to get it to work. Any help appreciated!

```
function getTime(zone, success) {
    var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=' + zone,
        ud = 'json' + (+new Date());
    window[ud]= function(o){
        success && success(new Date(o.datetime));
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild((function(){
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = url + '&callback=' + ud;
        return s;
    })());
}

getTime('GMT', function(time){

    if (time>10 && time<11)
  {
  document.write("<b>Paris</b>");
  }
    ;
});
```

Comment: Your'e missusing `document.write`. Now it clears all content in your page. You need to use some DOM-manipulation instead.

Comment: Since the text is not based on user's local time, shouldn't this be done on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a Date class.

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();

if(...) {
    // do something
}
```

This code extract

```
if (hour>10 && hour<11)
```

can't be working with hours, because time can't be > 10 and < 11 at the same time (hour is an int).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var now = new Date();
var utcMillis = now.getTime() + now.getTimzoneOffset() * 60000;
var hour = new Date(utcMillis).getHours(); // 0-23

switch(hour) {
  case 10: document.write("<b>Paris</b>"); break;
  //...
}
```

Some good info here: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329

You could also put your phrases in an array (which you might get from the server):

```
var phrases = ["Hi!", "blah", "more blah", ...];
```

... and then you can replace the switch above with:

```
document.write("<b>" + phrases[hour] + "</b>");
```

You might want to save yourself some time and use a framework that makes things work pretty much the same way across different browsers. [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) is my favorite, but there are plenty. Such libraries make it easy to manipulate content in your page, fetch JSON from the server, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

**At first sight:**

1. `o.datetime` is wrong formatted for JS Date method.
2. you return an instance of `new Date()` to get the hour use `.getHours()`

You can look here to find a way to convert your dateString from `o.datetime` [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

Use `time.getHours() > 12` instead of `time > 12`

If you use: `getDateFromFormat()` from http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/ I think the conversion will be something like `E, dd MMM hh:mm:ss +0000`

---

**SIMPLE ANSWER:**

You can just parse the `hour` to your callback: (See your JSON here http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=GMT)

```
function getTime(zone, success) {
    var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=' + zone,
        ud = 'json' + (+new Date());
    window[ud]= function(o){
        success && success(o.hour); // See o.hour here
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild((function(){
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = url + '&callback=' + ud;
        return s;
    })());
}

getTime('GMT', function(time){
    if (time>10 && time<11) {
        document.write("<b>Paris</b>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a quick jsfiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/eBAGS/5/ with a demo that should do what you need. It gets the time from the users PC rather than from a server though, but it could be modified.

**HTML**

```
<button onClick="getPhrase()">Show me a phrase for this hour</button>
<div id="placeHolder"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function getPhrase() {
    h = new Date().getHours(); //Get the current hour

    phrase = new Array(); //Create an array of phrases
    phrase[1] = 'Hello';
    phrase[2] = 'there';
    phrase[3] = 'this';
    phrase[4] = 'will';
    phrase[5] = 'show';
    phrase[6] = 'a';
    phrase[7] = 'different';
    phrase[8] = 'message';
    phrase[9] = 'depending';
    phrase[10] = 'on';
    phrase[11] = 'the';
    phrase[12] = 'hour';
    phrase[13] = 'of';
    phrase[14] = 'day';
    phrase[15] = 'that';
    phrase[16] = 'you';
    phrase[17] = 'look';
    phrase[18] = 'at';
    phrase[19] = 'it';
    phrase[20] = '!';
    phrase[21] = 'W';
    phrase[22] = 'X';
    phrase[23] = 'Y';
    phrase[24] = 'Z';

    document.getElementById('placeHolder').innerHTML = phrase[h-1]; //Show the array item relevant to the hour
}​
```