# Change date string and change DIV background color via onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this script that works, but I need to change the format of the date string to look different.  I'm currently getting: *Tue Apr 10 2012 22:27:13 GMT-0700 (PDT)*

I need the date string to look like this:  **April 10, 2012  10:28 PM**

I also need to change the DIV background thats holding the input forn the date string when the button is clicked.

```
<form>

<input name="theDate" size="50">

<input type="button" value="Insert date" 
  onclick="this.form.theDate.value = new Date();">

</form>
```

Comment: A lot of similar questions were already asked, for eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)!

> A lightweight (3.7k) javascript date library for parsing,
>   manipulating, and formatting dates.

Using moment.js...

```
var today = moment(new Date());
today.format("MMMM D, YYYY h:m A"); // outputs "April 11, 2012 12:44 AM"
```

You can even do it in one line :)

```
moment().format("MMMM D, YYYY h:m A"); // outputs "April 11, 2012 12:49 AM"
```

So for your input element...

```
<input type="button" value="Insert date" onclick="this.form.theDate.value = moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY h:m A');">
```

Also, its worth mentioning to checkout [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). I think the two libraries complement each other.

Comment: Can I add it to onclick="this.form.theDate.value = new Date();"

Comment: yes of course! you just need to include the javascript library.

Comment: I added the moment.js / Is this correct?  onclick="this.form.theDate.value = moment().format("MMMM D, YYYY h:m A")";

Comment: yes, that looks right. however, you have double quotes within double quotes... change it to this:  `onclick="this.form.theDate.value = moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY h:m A');"`

Comment: onclick="this.form.theDate.value = moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY h:m A');"

Comment: you must not have included the library properly... post your code up top

Comment: I got it to work.  thank you so much.  If I wanted to also change a div background at the same time, can I add it to the same line?

Comment: @Erik... technically yes, but I'd recommend moving it to an outside function; makes for cleaner code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9944/discussion-between-erik-and-hristo)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get different "times"-things:

```
For Year: date..getFullYear();
For Month: date.getMonth();
For Date: date.getDate();
For Hour: date.getHours();
For Minute: date.getMinutes();
     .
     .
     .
   etc. (date = new Date())
```

**Solution:** :D

```
var d = new Date(),
    y = d.getFullYear(),
    mo = d.getMonth(),
    da = d.getDate(),
    h = d.getHours(),
    m = d.getMinutes();

var time = m + " " + da + ", " + y + " " + h + ":" + m + ((h<12)?"AM":"PM");
```

**LIVE DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/GZ7sB/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `format` method of the `Date object` to format the dates as per your liking (provided in the `formatter` for which I have attached the link)...

**Example:**

```
var d = new Date();
d.format('m/dd/yy');
```

For additional information see [this link](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)...

Answer (score 0):

You can prune out the parts you want-

**alert(new Date().dayString('y','T'));**

> > returned value: (String) **April 11, 2012 1:58 AM**

```
String.prototype.padZero= function(len, c){
    var s= "", c= c || "0", len= (len || 2)- this.length;
    while(s.length<len) s += c;
    return s + this;
}

Date.daynames= ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday',
'Wednesday','Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

Date.ddmm= (function(){
    return Date.parse('2/6/2009')>Date.parse('6/2/2009');
})();

Date.monthnames= ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May',
'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

Date.prototype.dayString= function(wch, wch2){
    var D= this, A, day, M, W;
    wch= wch? wch.toLowerCase():'y';
    M= Date.monthnames;
    W= Date.daynames;
    var A= [W[D.getDay()], ' ', M[D.getMonth()], ' ',
    D.getDate(), ', ', D.getFullYear()];
    if(wch.indexOf('s')!= -1){
        A[0]= A[0].substring(0, 3);
        A[2]= A[2].substring(0, 3);
    }
    if(Date.ddmm ||  /b/i.test(wch)){
        A.splice(2, 3, A[4], A[3], A[2]);
    }
    if(wch.indexOf('y')== -1) A.length= 5;
    if(wch.indexOf('d')== -1) A.splice(0, 2);
    day= A.join('');
    if(wch2) day+= ' '+D.timeString(wch2);
    return day;
}
Date.prototype.timeString= function(sec){
    var D= this, A;
    sec= sec || '';
    var h= D.getHours();
    var w= h<12? ' am':' pm';
    if(sec===sec.toUpperCase())w=w.toUpperCase();
    if(h>12) h-= 12;
    else if(h== 0) h= 12;
    A= [h, String(D.getMinutes()).padZero(2)];
    if(/s/i.test(sec)) A[2]= String(D.getSeconds()).padZero(2);
    if(/ms/i.test(sec)) A[3]= String(D.getMilliseconds()).padZero(3);
    return A.join(':')+w;
}
```

Comment: jeez... nicely done, but why wouldn't you use an existing library?

Comment: How would I call this onclick?

Comment: @Hristo- I wrote this in 1998, before there were many javascript libraries around.

Comment: @kennebec... omg hahaha... awesome! I was in 3rd grade in 1998 :D at any rate, do check out moment.js! its really neat :)