# how to convert the string date to GMT date in js,

Tags: javascript

consider am having the string date and time.
say

```
var selfwDepDate    = document.forms[0].fwDepartureDate.value;
var selfwDepTime    = document.forms[0].fwDepartureTime.value;
```

and having time zone as

```
var orgTimeZone = document.getElementById('orginTimeZone').value;
var descTimeZone = document.getElementById('descTimeZone').value;
```

can any one how to convert the String date to GMT date..
value of orgTimeZone = Asia/Dubai
value of descTimeZone = America/New_York

Comment: Please check this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript

Comment: None of these helped? [convert one timezone to another](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+one+timezone+to+another+%5Djavascript%5B)

Comment: @Guruparan - not a very clear question to answer this one with - I would think >[this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)< more appropriate

Comment: hi thankz for the reply. guyz i need to convert the date to GMT i mean UTC,, so any one tell me, wats the reference time zone to convert that...var dt = new timezoneJS.Date(selfwDepDate,orgTimeZone );
  dt.setTimezone(?????);

 alert('final date'+ dt);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [timezone-js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js).

Create a timezoneJS.Date the same way as a normal JavaScript Date,
   but append a timezone parameter on the end:

```
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date('10/31/2008',
  'America/New_York');
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date(2008, 9, 31, 11, 45,
  'America/Los_Angeles');
```

OR

you can approach like this:-

```
var now = new Date();

var utc = new Date(Date.UTC(
    now.getFullYear(),
    now.getMonth(),
    now.getDate(),
    now.getHours(),
    now.getMinutes()
));
```

Now for different timezone you need to add or subtract the time by which they differ from GMT.
**Note** :-Date.UTC() returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch, UTC.

Comment: hey i got a page error fot var dt = new timezoneJS.Date('10/31/2008',
  'America/New_York');  since i passed date as 16-Apr-2012 06:30

Comment: any way to resolve this page error.. since my date format is dynamic

Comment: take the date from user but parse it in a proper format . you can search on SO, for lot of answers about how to parse a date format

Comment: even var dt = new timezoneJS.Date('10/31/2008',
    'America/New_York');
  alert('final date'+ dt); its not working.. do we need to have any jar for this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10110/discussion-between-meeran-and-pranav)

Comment: have u downloaded the src file and attached it  in your script tag:-  https://github.com/mde/timezone-js