# How to get month from string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have tried

```
     var d=new Date("2012-07-01 00:00:00.0");
     alert(d.getMonth());
```

But getting `NAN`.

I want month as `July` for the above date.

Comment: try this string= "2012-07-01 00:00:00". Could be that the last '.0' is causing the pare problem

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript if you want to parse in that format

Comment: try dis one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date-using-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get month name from Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming your date is in YYYY-MM-DD format

```
var arr = "2012-07-01 00:00:00.0".split("-");
var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
var month_index =  parseInt(arr[1],10) - 1;
console.log("The current month is " + months[month_index]);
```

Answer (score 20):

Using [the JavaScript Internationalization API](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/12/introducing-the-javascript-internationalization-api/):

```
var date = new Date("2012-07-01");

var monthName = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { month: "long" }).format;
var longName = monthName(date); // "July"

var shortMonthName = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { month: "short" }).format;
var shortName = shortMonthName(date); // "Jul"
```

Comment: Seems to be supported on every modern browser http://caniuse.com/#search=internationalization

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    var str="2012-07-01";   //Set the string in the proper format(best to use ISO format ie YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS)
    var d=new Date(str);  //converts the string into date object
    var m=d.getMonth(); //get the value of month
    console.log(monthNames[m]) // Print the month name
```

**NOTE:** The getMonth() returns the value in range 0-11.

Another option is to use `toLocaleString`

```
var dateObj = new Date("2012-07-01");
//To get the long name for month
var monthName = dateObj.toLocaleString("default", { month: "long" }); 
// monthName = "November"

//To get the short name for month
var monthName = dateObj.toLocaleString("default", { month: "short" });
// monthName = "Nov"
```

Comment: He wanted the months name

Comment: Superb . Really helped me

Answer (score 3):

use...

```
const month = new Date("2012-07-01 00:00:00.0").toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' });
const day = new Date("2012-07-01 00:00:00.0").toLocaleString('en-US', { day: '2-digit' });
```

This will make your day happy in easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an array for it: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

also why not initialise your date as:
var d = new Date(2012,7,1);

Answer (score 1):

Javascript Date object doesn't store full names of month. So you have to use an array.

```
var dateString = "2012-07-01 00:00:00.0";

var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var date = new Date(dateString.replace(" ", "T"));
alert(monthNames [date.getMonth()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
var months = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
   "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
document.write("The current month is " + months[d.getMonth()]);
```

> January->0, February-1 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to make things easier.
http://www.datejs.com/
And then try the following code:

```
var d=new Date.parse("2012-07-01 00:00:00.0");
 alert(d..tString('MMMM'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: with the above code most people will get an alert with `6` these days because Chrome and Firefox now understand that format. It's 6 and not 7 because `Date`s understand months as indexes beginning with 0, so 0 is Jan, 1 is Feb, 2 is Mar, etc. . So the simplest fix is this:

```
var d=new Date("2012-07-01 00:00:00.0");
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var monthIndex = d.getMonth();
alert(months[monthIndex]);
```

(Please consider using a different approach to constructing dates though!)

Long answer:

```
var d=new Date("2012-07-01 00:00:00.0");
```

The problem is you are getting an invalid date object because the browser doesn't understand that string. Browsers aren't consistent about this - Chrome and Firefox actually parse it correctly and will alert `6` instead of `NaN`. It's still not a good idea to be imprecise with your formats though - current Safari for example doesn't parse it. Formats that are guaranteed to work are described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3.

You might prefer to use this constructor though:

```
new Date(year, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

In your example, you would call it like so:

```
var d=new Date(2012, 6, 1);
```

Note the 6 and not 7 though! `Date`s understand months as indexes beginning with 0, so 0 is Jan, 1 is Feb, 2 is Mar, etc. . This is confusing when using the date constructor but easier to convert to `July` that was asked for:

```
var d=new Date(2012, 6, 1);
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var monthIndex = d.getMonth();
alert(months[monthIndex]);
```

You can learn more about `Date` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date