# Add new Spreadsheet in every month change

Tags: google-apps-script

Please tell me any code which add the new sheet in spreadsheet every new month and change the name of the sheet by the month name .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run an `onOpen()` function when the sheet is opened, check the date for what month and year it is, check if there is already a sheet with that name, and insert the sheet if one already does not exist.

### on Open:

[Documentation On Open](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopen)

### Date:

[Stack Overflow Question - Get Month in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246394/how-to-get-month-from-string-in-javascript)

### Try to retrieve a sheet by name of current month:

[Documentation Get Sheet by name](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))

### Condition:

```
If (sheetForCurrentMonthDoesntExist) {
  Insert Sheet;
};
```

### Insert Sheet:

[Documentation Insert Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String,Integer))