# JavaScript datetime parsing

Tags: javascript, parsing, datetime, format, datetime-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

I have a json response which contains a hashmap like;

```
{"map":{"2012-10-10 03:47:00.0":23.400000000000002,"2012-10-10 03:52:00.0":23.3,"2012-10-10 03:57:00.0":23.3,"2012-10-10 04:02:00.0":23.3,"2012-10-10 04:07:00.0":23.200000000000003,"2012-10-10 04:13:00.0":23.1,"2012-10-10 04:18:00.0":23.1,"2012-10-10 04:23:00.0":23.0,"2012-10-10 04:28:00.0":23.0,"2012-10-10 04:33:00.0":23.0,"2012-10-10 04:38:00.0":22.900000000000002,"2012-10-10 04:43:00.0":22.8,"2012-10-10 04:48:00.0":22.8,"2012-10-10 04:53:00.0":22.700000000000003,"2012-10-10 04:58:00.0":22.6,"2012-10-10 05:03:00.0":22.6,"2012-10-10 05:08:00.0":22.5,"2012-10-10 05:13:00.0":22.5,"2012-10-10 05:18:00.0":22.5,"2012-10-10 05:23:00.0":22.400000000000002}}
```

I want to format datetime part of json like;

> dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Lets assume I put all pair elements like this;

```
var myArr = [["2012-10-10 03:47:00.0", 23.400000000000002], ["2012-10-10 03:52:00.0", 23.3], ....];
```

Then, I try to parse datetime part like below and I got **Date {Invalid Date}** on console;

```
new Date(myArr[0][0]);
```

How can I format this type of datetime.

Comment: I do get a valid date out of `new Date(myArr[0][0])`. (And it should never throw an exception, in the first place.)

Comment: Actually, it is not an exception, when I use `console.log(new Date(myArr[0][0]));` its output `Date {Invalid Date}`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the following:

```
new Date(Date.parse(myArr[0][0]));
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m2hy5/)**

Use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).[parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method to parse the string into the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. Take that number of milliseconds and call the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) method once again to turn that time into a date object.

**EDIT**:

Well this may be a little ugly for this case, but it seems Firefox is having an issue with the `-`s and the `00.0`.

```
var myArr = [["2012-10-10 03:47:00.0", 23.400000000000002], ["2012-10-10 03:52:00.0", 23.3]];

var date = convertDateTime(myArr[0][0]);
console.log(date);

function convertDateTime(dateTime){
    dateTime = myArr[0][0].split(" ");

    var date = dateTime[0].split("-");
    var yyyy = date[0];
    var mm = date[1]-1;
    var dd = date[2];

    var time = dateTime[1].split(":");
    var h = time[0];
    var m = time[1];
    var s = parseInt(time[2]); //get rid of that 00.0;

    return new Date(yyyy,mm,dd,h,m,s);
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m2hy5/2/)**

Comment: On your example still have invalid date error

Comment: It gives error on firefox's console :/ Chrome renders fine.

Comment: `new Date` accepts a `Date.parse` string, as noted in the MDN article you linked to. Thus this answer would not solve the issue.

Comment: @vtokmak, the updated example should work for you and I would suggest creating a function that takes a string (`"2012-10-10 03:47:00.0"`) that way you can loop through your result set and call the function.

Answer (score 11):

```
function dateFromString(str) {
  var m = str.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\.(\d+)/);
  return new Date(+m[1], +m[2] - 1, +m[3], +m[4], +m[5], +m[6] * 100);
}

dateFromString(myArr[0][0]); // Sat Oct 10 2012 03:47:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Comment: Slight variation to support Facebook dates: str.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)[\sT]+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)[.+](\d+)/)

Comment: Why `m[6] * 100`? m[6] is just seconds, should be passed to the Date constructor without a multiplicator.