# Jquery start time end time validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

I have the code given below for validating the start time and end time.

It works to some extend but when I give start time *9:00 AM* and End time *1:00 PM* it does not work.

```
$("#dateTimeAddButton").click(function () 
{                       
        var Date = $("#myDatePickerId").val();

        var startTime = $("#start-Time").val();
        var endTime = $("#end-Time").val(); 

        if(startTime > endTime)
           alert('end time always greater then start time');

});
```

Someone help me with this.Thanks in advance

Comment: No.I am looking for a solution which doesn't use jquery validator plugin.

Comment: So... you're directly comparing the strings "9:00 AM" and "1:00 PM" and wondering why JavaScript doesn't know what those mean?

Comment: first one is my datepicker id,second one id of the text box which has the start time value,and second one which have the end time value

Comment: i just gave a scenario where it does not work.if the end time is less than start time regardless of it is AM or PM,it this does not work.

Comment: You need to [convert those strings into datetime objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/476105/901048) before you can compare them.

Comment: Ok..let me see that..thankx for the hint

Comment: I do not need the date here.I just need the time.Give me a way to get time only please.

Comment: Date/time is one object in JavaScript - you need to add SOME date even if you don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modification to the solution proposed by @Palash

```
 var startDate = new Date($('#start-Time').val());
 var endDate = new Date($('#end-Time').val());

 if (startDate.getTime() > endDate.getTime()){
 // Do something 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two strings, you are not comparing Date objects. You need to convert them to a time format.