# Convert string to date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a string looking like so:

```
"2013/1/16"
```

Is there any way I could quickly convert it into date object in javascript, something like:

```
convertToDateTime("2013/1/16", "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Comment: look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
var myDate = new Date("2013/1/16");
```

That should do the trick.
Have a look at the [documentation for the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: i do `new Date("12-01-2019")` and it gives me `Sun Dec 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` . what if i want the date object to be the 12th Jan and not 1st December

Comment: @Abhi
Use substr function to change the date to 2019-01-12 and add "T00:00:00" to it, to make it look like:
"2019-01-12T00:00:00"

This way, Date object knows it is a date in ISO format and it correctly detects month and day.

Comment: Time zones can present a confusing (and I hope I don't make it worse here).  yada = new Date("2013/1/16") returns an object representing 12AM in the time zone of the machine on which that code is run, in my case 
Wed Jan 16 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
yada.getUTCHours() retuns 8 - the corresponding time in London.
8

Answer (score -1):

var myDate = new Date("2013/1/16");

var str = "2013/1/16";
var strToDate = new Date(str);

Comment: How is this answer different from the accepted answer?