# jQuery week calendar appointments only appear in Chrome, but not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, browser

I have a strange problem. I am using [jQuery weekcalendar](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar) to show appointments in a calendar in the browser.

Everything is fine with Chrome. All my appointments are shown. In all other browsers, I only see the calendar, but not the appointments.

This is the link to my [calendar](http://www.slinder.ch/admin/admin/calendar/calendar.html).

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here? I don't know what code I should add to this question, as I have no idea where the problem is located. But the code is visible if you check the page source.

Comment: it could be `eventData1` from the AJAX response isn't populating fast enough (except in Chrome).  You might want to initialize the calendar (`$('#calendar').weekCalendar({ ... })`) after the AJAX success callback instead of on `document.ready`

Comment: But therefore I am using 'async:false', shouldn't that work this way?

Comment: never use `async:false`. Is now deprecated

Comment: also your `$.ajax` call is declared outside a `$(document).ready()` function, could be related.

Comment: I added `$.ajax` to the `$(document).ready()` function, I inizialize  `($('#calendar').weekCalendar({ ... }))` after the AJAX success callback but still the same problem. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem has to do with the way you are parsing the date coming from the ajax call 'http://www.slinder.ch/admin/php/termin_getappointments.php'.  You are using "new Date()" to convert to Date.  Although this is working fine in chrome, it is not working in other browsers.  Try parsing your date format as explained in the following post:

[How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

The answer that has the following code sample seems to be sufficient and it uses the exact date format returned by the ajax call:

```
var dateString = "2010-08-09 01:02:03";
var reggie = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
var dateArray = reggie.exec(dateString); 
var dateObject = new Date(
    (+dateArray[1]),
    (+dateArray[2])-1, // Careful, month starts at 0!
    (+dateArray[3]),
    (+dateArray[4]),
    (+dateArray[5]),
    (+dateArray[6])
);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it doesn't work. Now even Chrome is not able to display the events.

Comment: In your code you reversed the start and end date in the appointments.push...  start should by set to startFormatted and end should be set to endFormatted.

Comment: Genius! My mistake, sorry! It now works in every Browser :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Btw, I will award the bounty tomorrow. It is blocked for the next 22 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this code:

```
appointments.push({
  id: id,
  start: new Date(start),
  end: new Date(end),
  title: '<b>' + title + '</b> - ' + body,
  userId: userid
});
```

Should be:

```
appointments.push({
  id: id,
  start: moment(start, "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
  end: moment(end, "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
  title: '<b>' + title + '</b> - ' + body,
  userId: userid
});
```

Comment: Hi Yuriy. I tried this, but now it doesn't work in any of the browsers, no appointment is shown.