# How to convert javascript date to GMT milliseconds?

Tags: javascript

I have the following date:

```
var datestr = "11/11/2012 10:55"
```

When I do the following:

```
var datems = new Date(datestr).getTime();
```

The milliseconds I get do not appear to be the correct milliseconds as it appears to be much farther ahead in time. How do i convert the "datestr" above to milliseconds (in respect to GMT)?

Comment: `getTime` description - "Returns the numeric value of the specified date as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC (negative for prior times)." - the problem might be that your date string isn't being parsed correctly. What happens when you `console.log(new Date(datestring));`?

Comment: I've deleted my answer as I was addressing the wrong issue. What value of milliseconds are you receiving? I suspect it is a Time Zone issue as @Jonathon Lonowksi points out in his answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that `Date` assumes **local time** if the string doesn't specify a timezone.

If all of your date strings are in that format, you can append a timezone to them when parsing:

```
var datems = new Date(datestr + " UTC").getTime();
```

Or you'll have to use the [local offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) to find UTC:

```
var localDate = new Date(datestr);
var datems = localDate.getTime() - (localDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
```