# How to convert string to date format in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can convert a string to date format in java script.
I want to convert this string "Wed May 15 2013 11:30:00 GMT 0530 (IST)" into a date format.

Comment: You mean like `var time = new Date(); return time.toString();` ?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Check the post imkost linked and if you still have problems getting the right format, write in your question what format you need the datetime to be in.

Comment: Yes Simon you are right you got my point. I want to in the following format :- "YY-MM-dd"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date.parse` function

```
// create Date object from string
var d = new Date(Date.parse("Wed May 15 2013 11:30:00 GMT 0530 (IST)"));
var dateString = d.getFullYear()+"-"+(d.getMonth()+1)+"-"+d.getDate();
```

Comment: Actually, you can remove `Date.parse` and feed it directly into the `Date` constructor

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="javascript">
   var dateTime = new Date(); 
   alert(dateTime.toString());
</script>
```

Here is the working Demo: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uCGk8/)

Comment: Sounds like the opposite of what the OP wants to do