# how to select a input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

My html is look like below (it's not a html I'm echoing this using PHP. And it has lot of `<li></li>` with same 3 inputs content. It's a dynamically generated one)

```
<li><span class='add-on'></span>" .
    "<input class='' type='text' value='' />
    <input class='picker' type='hidden' value='' name=''  />
    <input class='datepicker' type='text' />
</li>
```

I want to select first input using CSS. I tried first-child but no luck.we can't put any class or Id to that first input. Because I was write another JS script to find non class inputs. So I want to select that first input using jQuery. And I need to put that first input value and datepicker class value to hidden input value. I was try following script. But I don't know how to select that input using jQuery.

jQuery

```
var getDate = $(".datepicker").val();
var getMark = $("I want to any select to select first input").val();
var plusVal = getDate + getMark;

$(".picker").val(plusVal);
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
li > span + input { /* styles here */ }
```

jQuery:

```
$('li > span + input').val();
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmwF7/).

Comment: var getDate = $(".datepicker").val();
    var getMark = $('li > span + input').val();
    var plusVal = getDate + getMark;

    $(".picker").val(plusVal);
alert(plusVal);

Comment: Your question was answered. How to cast to datetime would be another question. Maybe something like "[How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)"

Answer (score 0):

If you can depend on CSS3, then you can use `li > input:first-of-type` or `li > input:nth-of-type:(1)`. Otherwise you could use `li > span + input`