# How to extract part of an Object in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to extract the value of datetime from each of the following array objects:

```
[<time pubdate class="dt-updated" datetime="2015-07-09T11:50:32+0000" title="Time posted: 09 Jul 2015, 11:50:32 (UTC)" aria-label="Posted on 09 Jul">09 Jul</time>, <time pubdate class="dt-updated" datetime="2015-06-18T13:59:49+0000" title="Time posted: 18 Jun 2015, 13:59:49 (UTC)" aria-label="Posted on 18 Jun">18 Jun</time>, <time pubdate class="dt-updated" datetime="2015-06-18T12:56:47+0000" title="Time posted: 18 Jun 2015, 12:56:47 (UTC)" aria-label="Posted on 18 Jun">18 Jun</time>, <time pubdate class="dt-updated" datetime="2015-06-18T12:41:42+0000" title="Time posted: 18 Jun 2015, 12:41:42 (UTC)" aria-label="Posted on 18 Jun">18 Jun</time>]
```

Does anyone know if theres a method for array objects that helps me do this when I create my loop? My searching online hasn't found anything so far...

Comment: use regular expressions to find it.

Comment: so those are dom elements? how did you get them?

Comment: As far as JavaScript goes those array elements are illegal. If you want to make that data usable you need to either convert it to strings or some other kind of data that is actually accessible by JavaScript.

Comment: Got them from a regex of a JSON I retrieved

Comment: can you provide the full json?

Comment: If you already had all the data in JSON why even convert it to array elements?

Comment: http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/c20f25

Comment: but that is just a string in the json, not an array?!

Comment: Do you have an array of HTML strings? It's completely unclear what you have. If you have an array of objects, it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865/218196.

Comment: OK so regex was performed on the JSON extracting all the <time> elements and placing them in an array. When I perform typeof on array[0] is tells me it's an object. So from what I can tell I have an array full of objects (the <time> elements). I want to extract the value of datetime from each object in the array. FYI the array itself is used for other things as well, I haven't created it just for this purpose.

Comment: But a regular expression only works on strings. It does not magically create `<time>` elements. Please post a **complete** example of your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript

Comment: You can see the code that extracts the <time> elements from the JSON at clarkben.com/tweetsatwedding/index.html. See tweets.js: function getElementsByClassName at line 74 that is called on line 188.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a regex match `datetime="(.*?)"`

https://regex101.com/r/wE0mZ8/1

This will put all your datetime values into an array:

```
var str = '[<time pubdate class="dt-updated" datetime="2015-07-09T11:50:32+0000" title="Time posted: 09 Jul 2015, 11:50:32 (UTC)" aria-label="Posted on 09 Jul">09 Jul</time>, <time pubdate class="dt-updated" datetime="2015-06-18T13:59:49+0000" title="Time posted: 18 Jun 2015, 13:59:49 (UTC)" aria-label="Posted on 18 Jun">18 Jun</time>, <time pubdate class="dt-updated" datetime="2015-06-18T12:56:47+0000" title="Time posted: 18 Jun 2015, 12:56:47 (UTC)" aria-label="Posted on 18 Jun">18 Jun</time>, <time pubdate class="dt-updated" datetime="2015-06-18T12:41:42+0000" title="Time posted: 18 Jun 2015, 12:41:42 (UTC)" aria-label="Posted on 18 Jun">18 Jun</time>]';
var res = str.match(/datetime="(.*?)"/gi); 
alert (res[0]);
```