# Convert datetime to date format?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Datetime has format like this: var datetime = "2015-10-19T22:50:00.000+02:00"

How can I convert it to 19 Oct, 2015 ?

Thank you so much

Comment: This question really shows that no attempt was made at all to research this

Comment: `new Date("2015-10-19T22:50:00.000+02:00").toUTCString().split(" ").slice(1,4).join(" ")`

Comment: In pure JS is a long answer, but you should look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for a solid library to handle dates.

Comment: @1cgonza: isn't moment a lot longer than calling a few methods? last i checked it was dozens of KBs... Moment is good for somethings, especially parsing, but date formatting in vanilla is not as bad as people make it out to be...

Comment: Thank all but I need fast solution. Thank so much !!!!!

Comment: @dandavis depends… does OP want the output in local timezone, UTC, …? can't really extrapolate from a single example and no intentional description of what he wants. Moment is tens of kb but that may be worth the convenience of having a reliable, easy-to-use library.

Comment: @Touffy: that's all true enough, i just find that whipping up a custom date formatter never takes me more than a few lines of vanilla. i think people look at crappy methods like .getHours() and freak out, instead of using a timezoneoffset-adjust UTC flavor to get the date parts, or replace()ing an existing standard string output into the format they need...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

```
var datetime = "2015-10-19T22:50:00.000+02:00"
new Date(datetime).toDateString()
```

Comment: `toDateString()` is browser-dependent, so your code might not always produce the desired format...

Comment: also doesn't produce expected results

Comment: @dandavis well, it's hard to tell if that really matters to OP. I'd suggest using moment if he'd ask a bit better.