# Serialize Date from mongodb to nodejs mongoose

Tags: date, mongoose

My problem is that I've got objects with date property,and I want to filter by date in my front-end application (using angularJS).

but unfortunately the mongoose serialize the object as key-value strings
example of object :

```
"_id":123456,
Name :"Adam",
Family: "Levine",
Date : ISODate("2017-02-22T22:00:00:00Z"),
"__v":0
```

but when Im do Model.find() mongoose function, Im get this object :

```
"_id":123456,
Name :"Adam",
Family: "Levine",
Date : "2017-02-22T22:00:00:00Z"
```

how can I fix that problem ?

Answer (score 0):

When MongoDB/Mongoose serializes the object it turns it into JSON.

JSON values can only be of type object, array, number, string, true, false or null. Check out the [ECMA-404 The JSON Data Interchange Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) Section 5 or Douglas Crockford's [JSON](http://www.json.org/) site.

Given that we know it can only be one of the above values, we know that mongoose is serializing it into a string. It is your job to convert it into an actual JavaScript date object. You can either manually take the date and parse it yourself or you can use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) that will handle much of the parsing/formatting and other date related functions for you.

Also take a look at some other StackOverflow questions that may help you.

- [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)
- [Converting String to Date in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)