# Convert string 'time' into a datetime

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a string time (ie: 1100) to a DateTime using the current day/month/year and the given time.

This is what I'm currently doing, and isn't working properly...

```
data.BeginTime = 1100
beginTime = new Date(data.BeginTime)
```

EDIT:

I figured it out with the following:

```
var d = new Date();
var bT = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay(), data.BeginTime / 100, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

Comment: Is 1100 a time? Don't you mean 11:00?

Comment: @trincot it can either be 1100 or 11:00 a.m.     I'd prefer not to have to write another function to format the data, but it's not out of the question.

Comment: @DannyBuonocore Not a duplicate, I don't have the date aspect so this is different

Comment: `1100` is a number not a string. Do you mean `'1100'`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a function like this:

```js
function todayAtTime(militaryTime) {
    var minutes = militaryTime % 100;
    var hours = Math.floor((militaryTime - minutes) / 100);
    var dt = new Date();
    dt.setUTCHours(hours);
    dt.setUTCMinutes(minutes);
    dt.setUTCSeconds(0);
    dt.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
    return dt;
}

// Example call
var result = todayAtTime(1100); 

// Output result
console.log(result);
```

This is UTC Date Time. If you are going to use the date as a locale date time, then leave out the "UTC" part in the method calls, and print as `result.toLocaleString()`.