# How to convert month in word instead of number in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file there is data coming from JSON but here is format like `06/12/2020` but I have to convert this format like `June 12 2020`.

How can I do this?

Current Code:-

```
 {pageData.map(x =>
  <tr>
  <td>{x.date}</td>
  <td>{x.name}</td>
  <td>{x.language}</td>
  <td><a href={x.link} target="_blank" class="btn">Click to Listen</a></td>
  </tr>
  )}
```

Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: The solution you need is twofold: 1) parse `06/12/2020` into variables or a `Date` 2) output as `June 12 2020`. Both questions have tons of existing answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get month name from Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base on [Date doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), you just need to create a date object like this:

```
<td>{new Date(x.date).toLocaleDateString('en-En',{ year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' })}</td>
```

Comment: Parsing a date string like _"06/12/2020"_ with the `Date` constructor is not recommended